# RMI Test Passes in Isolation but Fails with UnmarshalException When Run with Other Tests

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to understand why a specific test method that utilizes RMI passes when run in isolation but fails when run along with other tests that also use RMI. The test structure is the same for both cases.

```
...

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeTest() throws Exception {
    try {
      System.setProperty(Constants.JAVA_RMI_TEST_PORT_ENVIRONMENT, TestEnvironment.getPort());
      dataFactory.register();
      await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      client = DataFactoryClient.getInstance(TestEnvironment.getDomain(), TestEnvironment.getPort());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void afterAll() {
    dataFactory.release();
  }


  @Test
  public void testSimpleSave() throws Exception {
    EntityStore entityStore = client.getEntityStore();
    Assert.assertNotNull(entityStore);

    DataFactoryEntity entity = new DataFactoryEntityBuilder()
            .environment(TestEnvironment.getEnvironment())
            .entityType("Foo")
            .putPropertyMap("foo", "bar")
            .build();

    DataFactoryEntity dataFactoryEntity = entityStore.saveEntity(entity).get();
    Assert.assertNotNull(dataFactoryEntity);
    Assert.assertNotNull(dataFactoryEntity.entityId());
    Assert.assertEquals("bar", dataFactoryEntity.propertyMap().get("foo"));
  }
```

```
public class EntityStoreClientImpl implements EntityStore {
  @Override public Option<DataFactoryEntity> saveEntity(@NotNull DataFactoryEntity entity)
      throws DataFactoryException, NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    return getEntityStore().saveEntity(entity);
  }
}
```

The test method `testSimpleSave` fails if not run in isolation. When run alongside the other tests it throws:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: ....datafactory.database.impl.DatabaseManagerImpl

    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:130)
    at ....datafactory.repositories.impl.EntityStoreClientImpl.getEntityStore(EntityStoreClientImpl.java:108)
    at ....datafactory.repositories.impl.EntityStoreClientImpl.saveEntity(EntityStoreClientImpl.java:56)
    at ....datafactory.DataFactoryClientTest.testSimpleSave(DataFactoryClientTest.java:75
```

It is not supposed to serialize `DatabaseManagerImpl` (which is not meant to be anyway) like the other unit test. What's puzzling is why this particular test is attempting to serialize it.

The whole test code can be [checked here](https://github.com/divroll/datafactory/blob/eb5706ee512f755a0255ff7c8c9b552f3d05e8ea/src/test/java/com/divroll/datafactory/DataFactoryClientTest.java) for verbosity.

I could use some help and would greatly appreciate it!

**Update:**

Here is a quick reference to a similar test that can pass:

```
  @Test
  public void testNearbyConditionWithGeoHash() throws Exception {
    String environment = TestEnvironment.getEnvironment();
    EntityStore entityStore = DataFactoryClient.getInstance(TestEnvironment.getDomain(), TestEnvironment.getPort()).getEntityStore();

    DataFactoryEntity firstLocation = new DataFactoryEntityBuilder()
        .environment(environment)
        .entityType("Room")
        .putPropertyMap("address", "Room 123, 456 Street, 789 Avenue")
        .putPropertyMap("geoLocation", new GeoHash(120.976171, 14.580919).toString())
        .build();
    firstLocation = entityStore.saveEntity(firstLocation).get();
    assertNotNull(firstLocation.entityId());
...
```

Comment: Evidently `datafactory.database.impl.DatabaseManagerImpl` is meant to be a remote object, but it isn't exported, so it isn't a remote object, so it doesn't get substituted by its stub.

Comment: This is quite baffling as other unit tests use the same connection class but do not attempt to serialize the `DatabaseManagerImpl`.

Comment: Sure. You need to look into where it gets initialized and exported. Somehow it got bound into the Registry in an unexported state. So it was running in the same JVM as the Registry.

Comment: Note that these two tests get the `entityStore` in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong here as it has been a while since written RMI server, and it is hard to see what you code does, so will delete if this doesn't help.

RMI depends on serialisation, so any non-transient member fields are candidates for transfer between client and server. I see that `EntityStoreImpl` contains non-transient reference to `DatabaseManager`. When binding to registry with `dataFactory.register()`, you use the implementation class:

```
  entityStore = new EntityStoreImpl(DatabaseManagerImpl.getInstance(), LuceneIndexerImpl.getInstance());
  registry.rebind(EntityStore.class.getName(), entityStore);
```

Normally I'd expect to see a generated stub so the implementation class is not referenced directly, something like this:

```
  EntityStore stub = (EntityStore )UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(entityStore, 0);
  registry.rebind(EntityStore.class.getName(), stub);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, full fix has been committed: https://github.com/divroll/datafactory/commit/a9aef554c667353b51c0c19026c1b08182483ce0